# File not uploading in Express JS using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am creating API using express JS. Now, I have a router which will be used to upload image using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Here is my router :

```js
const multer = require('multer');

module.exports = (app) => {
  const DIR = './public/';

  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, DIR);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null , file.originalname);
    }
  });

  const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

  // I have also tried this but not working
  // const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

  app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "File uploaded successfully"
    });
  });
}
```

Now, from my reactjs app I am calling this router using **axios** like this :

```js
const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
}
const body = new FormData();
body.append('image', this.state.selectedCategoryImage);
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/upload', body, { headers }).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

In above code `this.state.selectedCategoryImage` is a selected image from html `<input>` tag.

Now, When I call this api I am getting my response "file uploaded successfully", but I am not able to see my uploaded image anywhere in public directory. My image is not uploading.

Please anyone can help me what's the issue ?

Comment: What does it display if you add `console.log(req.file.path)` just before `res.status(201)....`?

Comment: @SuleymanSah it displays `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

Comment: So it means file is not available. Do you have  `type="file"` inside your input tag?

Comment: Yes, input type is file.

Comment: What does it display when you `console.log(this.state.selectedCategoryImage)` just before axios.post?

Comment: It displays `blob:http://localhost:3001/adde937a-3841-4f61-9e33-663bb50885c1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207246/discussion-between-kishan-bharda-and-suleymansah).

Comment: you are converting file into blob url to show on screen preview and you are passing that url but pass file what you got in input "event.target.files[0]"
that way it send file object

Comment: Thanks @virendernehra. It worked. I would like to access it as a solution if you post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pass file Object not URL

`URL.createObjectURL(file) // it return file url that you can use to show file preview`

## For upload file, send actual file in axios API as you got from file input

`var file = event.target.files[0]; // return actual file`

this way it actually send file object.